# How to save a variable in symfony between pages?

Tags: php, class, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony and in my actions class I handle an execute function that performs some actions. Within that function I want to save a variable to the class so that I can reference it later. Is there any way to do this without writing to a database or using global PHP POST variables?

Like, in the executeIndex function I save a variable to class scope and then later when the executeEdit function is called I can retrieve that value? Can this be done?

Comment: How about a session variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Friek said, you can use session:

```
// store into the session
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('my_var', $var);

// fetch var already stored in the session
$my_var = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('my_var', null);
```

Or you can use `sfConfig`, if your variable is about configuration:

```
// define a setting
sfConfig::set('my_var', $var);

// Retrieve a setting
$my_var = sfConfig::get('my_var', null);
```

Comment: Also possible to pass as URL parameters as well but not as clean as using session variables as @jOk answered